# Sqlite getting the latest record for this table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. I am querying sqlite table the to get the latest record for each College but the result is not completely accurate. Below is the source table:

```
College  Status           Date
"UTAR   "CERTIFIED" "07/30/2018"
"UTA"   "CERTIFIED" "03/19/2018"
"UTD"   "CERTIFIED" "06/08/2018"
"UTEL"  "CERTIFIED" "03/13/2018"
"UTSA"  "CERTIFIED" "02/06/2018"
"UTT"   "CERTIFIED" "03/14/2018"
"UTPB"  "CERTIFIED" "07/23/2018"
"UTRG"  "CERTIFIED" "04/12/2018"
"UTAR"  "CERTIFIED" "05/31/2017"
"UTA"   "CERTIFIED" "03/02/2017"
"UTD"   "CERTIFIED" "04/13/2017"
"UTEL"  "CERTIFIED" "03/10/2017"
"UTSA"  "CERTIFIED" "02/13/2017"
"UTT"   "CERTIFIED" "03/11/2017"
"UTPB"  "CERTIFIED" "03/29/2017"
"UTRG"  "CERTIFIED" "04/12/2017"
```

and this  is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Status_Table AS S1
WHERE Date = (
                 SELECT MAX(Date)
                 FROM Status_Table AS S2
                 WHERE S1.College = S2.College
                                              );
```

and the result is:

```
College  Status           Date
"UTAR"  "CERTIFIED" "07/30/2018"
"UTA"   "CERTIFIED" "03/19/2018"
"UTD"   "CERTIFIED" "06/08/2018"
"UTEP"  "CERTIFIED" "03/13/2018"
"UTT"   "CERTIFIED" "03/14/2018"
"UTPB"  "CERTIFIED" "07/23/2018"
"UTRG"  "CERTIFIED" "04/12/2018"
"UTSA"  "CERTIFIED" "02/13/2017"
```

if you notice in the case of UTSA it did not pick up the latest date of 02/06/2018. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the data type of Date column?

Comment: What is the data type?  Also I think you can change yoru query to an inner join

Comment: The data type is Date.

Comment: Can you provide a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/28f6a6/1/0

Comment: There is no Date datatype in sqlite, the column is treated as numeric. See 2.2 in https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: in create table let's you define Date type. But regardless how do I do this in sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be related the the column type. From the SQLite document [about date time](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype),

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:

I don't know why there is no warning or error when you created the table, but it seems that the comparison is using string comparison instead of date. The column is changed to `TEXT` and the date format 'YYYY-MM-DD' is applied in my sql fiddle. Then using `date` function in the query and everything seems work.

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/148299/1)

Comment: That's interesting. I tried the text data type previously and had similar issue as the Max(date) should not work on text data type. However, it worked in this case. Perhaps I had more data point previously. Thanks for the info anyways.

Answer (score -2):

You need group by Max date. Try this -

```
SELECT *
FROM Status_Table
WHERE Date IN (SELECT MAX(Date)
               FROM Status_Table
               GROUP BY College);
```

Comment: the sub select returns two columns College and Date you can't check Date column with that sub query.